# Recalculate transform origin on a scaled element

Tags: javascript, css, math, formula, scale

I have an element which has to be scaled from 100px from the left while already having a scale of 0.5. When transforming the origin it is on 50px on the left side and scaling from the wrong side of the line.

When scaling the element I want it to scale from the purple line. Without using the left CSS property.

I tried to use this formula but it was slightly off:

x + (x * scale)

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.example-initial {
  background: blue;
  transform: scale(0.2);
  transform-origin: 100px 0px;
}

.example-wrong {
  background: green;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 100px 0px;
}

.example-right {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 200px 0px;
}

.transform-origin-line-example {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
  background: purple;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-initial box"></div>

<div class="example-wrong box"></div>

<div class="example-right box"></div>

<div class="transform-origin-line-example"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is:

`(x * (1 / (1 - 0.1));`

`x` is the left position.
`1` is the full scale.
`0.1` is the used scale.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  transform-origin: calc(100px * (1 / 0.9)) 0px;
} 

.example-box {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: calc(100px * (1 / 0.5))  0px;
}

.transform-origin-line-example {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="example-box"></div>

<div class="transform-origin-line-example"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just fix the transform-origin code as
`transform: scale(-0.5);`

Comment: No, when scaling the element I want it to scale from the purple line. Without using the left CSS property.

Comment: Yes while aligning on the purple line. No worries I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Can you try `transform: scale(-0.5);` instead ?